# duplicate results on join sql

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have two SQL scripts. I need to combine data from the both of them. I've set them up as two seperate volatile tables to join them together for my finished report. The script below is a just an example of what I'm trying to extract from the data. The true script is very complex, and has many sub queries meriting the need to use a volitile table instead of just a regular join. The join is on the "customer_acct".The purpose of this script is to produce a record of all orders, and then have a column on whether or not a refund has been applied to said order, tied by the "customer_acct".

The result that I get gives me

```
CUST_ACCT    PRODUCT_ORDERED    REFUND_AMT
1111111      item#5             10.00
1111111      item#5             20.00
1111111      item#5             30.00
2222222      item#5             10.00
2222222      item#5             20.00
2222222      item#5             30.00
3333333      item#5             10.00
3333333      item#5             20.00
3333333      item#5             30.00
```

My script is summarized below.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE ORDERS, NO LOG AS(
SELECT 
p.customer_acct
p.product_ordered
etc.
FROM server p
)WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (p.customer_acct)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE REFUND, NO LOG AS(
SELECT
c.customer_acct
c.refund_amt
c.date
etc.
FROM server c
)WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (c.customer_acct)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS; 

SELECT DISTINCT
a.cust_acct
,a.product_ordered
,b.refund_amt

FROM ORDERS a

LEFT Join REFUND B
on b.cust_Accta = a.customer_acct
;

DROP TABLE ORDERS;
DROP TABLE REFUND;
```

Basically, the script is returning a result for every line in the 'Orders' line, and duplicating it by every possible value in the 'Refund' table, despite not having any real matches.

Any idea? I apologize up front, as SQL is relatively new to me and I'm trying to expand my knowledge.

Comment: Next time pls use only the relevant product type tags, do not just randomly select those, that contain the letters sql!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the join that you have a problem with. You need to aggregate the data from the refund table by account number to get only a single row by account number.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.cust_acct
,a.product_ordered
,case when count(b.cust_Accta)=0 then 'no refund' else 'refund' end as refund

FROM ORDERS a

LEFT Join REFUND B
on b.cust_Accta = a.customer_acct
GROUP BY a.customer_acct
```

Or you can use sum() to get back the refund amount:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.cust_acct
,a.product_ordered
,sum(b.refund_amt) as refund_amount

FROM ORDERS a

LEFT Join REFUND B
on b.cust_Accta = a.customer_acct
GROUP BY a.customer_acct
```

Comment: thank you for the assistance. I've added the sum() suggestion but now I'm getting an error that selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group. I've added the groupby, but still getting the error...

Comment: Then you have more fields in the select clause of your query than you disclised in your question. If you do not provide full details in your question,  we cannot provide an appropriate answer!

Comment: Its not that I don't want to, but its quite hard to post without giving out proprietary data. Can you help me understand whats causing this? Each record in the orders table is being posted three times, as it just so happens there are 3 values available as the "refund" amount.

Comment: I ended up figuring out my mistake. Thank you for your patience @shadow

Answer (score 0):

You are joining in customer acct. there are 3 records where this accoun id is common.  So it repeats thrice. In join you need to add another condition, equivalent to/similar to  'where A.item = B.item or A.orderno=B.orderno' . I cannot write it exactly, as you have not mentioned the column names.

Comment: I just confirmed that there are no duplicates. Each record in the orders table is being posted three times, as it just so happens there are 3 values available as the "refund" amount.

Comment: @CRudiger ,  If every row originally repeated thrice, you will have 27 lines in output, since the resultset is cross product with no order no / item no in the join. Anyway you are not going to understand.